# como fazer dois inserts no php

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando fazer dois inserts no php assim:

```
function insereProduto($conexao, $nome, $cor, $preco){
    $sql="insert into produtos (nome, cor) values ('{$nome}','{$cor}')");
     $sql2="insert into preco (preco) value ({$preco});");
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $sql. ";". $sql2);
}
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Algo está muito estranho no seu código. Depois que você insere 2 produtos ou mais, como sabe qual preço é de qual produto? Se isso foi um exercício passado, fica a recomendação de quem elaborou revisar a metodologia. Exercício com condição artificial demais prejudica o aluno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa de uma string de conexão, no caso a `$sql` ficará assim:

```
$sql = "insert into produtos ...; insert into preco ...;";
mysqli_multi_query($conexao, $sql);
```

O seu erro foi referênciar as duas querys dentro do multi_query, para dar tudo certo você deveria atribuir os dois valores a uma única query.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como o multi_query recebe seus parametros e note que ele reconhece apenas uma string:

```
mysqli_multi_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )
```

Para mais detalhes sobre o mysql multi_query: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou

Comment: O erro foi somente o fato de não usar multi_query. A concatenação da pergunta não tem nenhum problema, e sim a função. Teria funcionado com `$sql. ";". $sql2` sem problemas se quem fez a pergunta tivesse usado a função adequada.